# How to change volume/alter AudioClip

Tags: java, audio, volume, audioclip

I've seen methods to change Clip volume, however, I am using an AudioClip (code below). Is there a good way to change the volume of the clip? Or would I have to instead use a Clip?

```
    private static AudioClip getcharend() {
    File file = new File("charend.wav");
    AudioClip clip;
    try {
        clip = JApplet.newAudioClip(file.toURL());
        clip.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }

    return clip;
}
```

Comment: Applet AudioClip has no support for volume setting. It may be better to use Clip from javax.sound to control the volume.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html)

> The relative volume level at which the clip is played. Valid range is
>   0.0 (muted) to 1.0 (full volume). Values are clamped to this range internally so values outside this range will have no additional
>   effect. Volume is controlled by attenuation, so values below 1.0 will
>   reduce the sound level accordingly.

Since the clip object is being returned. you can just use it to set volume. For example calling your Method above in my code

```
AudioClip audioClip = getcharend(); 
audioClip.setVolume(0.9);
```

Comment: It says setVolume is undefined for type AudioClip.

Comment: This is just incorrect. He asked about Applet clip and you linked him docs from JavaFX